# How to format usage messages such that function templates are parsed correctly?

Tags: front-end, bugs, version-9, usage-messages

Is it possible to format usage messages (with italic arguments etc) such that Mathematica 9 still parses function templates correctly?

For example, plain usage messages work when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

[image]

But formatted ones don't:

[image]

Note that this does work correctly on Mathematica 8, so I guess this is a bug on Mathematica 9.0.1. Nonetheless, is there a workaround?

Comment: There are also major problems with this functionality working with add-on packages too.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug. Thanks.

Comment: @Teake Did you get any response from Wolfram Tech Support confirming this is a bug? If so, could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: I didn't report this; perhaps @user21 received some feedback?

Comment: @TeakeNutma user21 does not care :) so maybe you could report this? :)

Answer (score 7):

This specific example works Mathematica 10.0.2:

[image]

However, there are several variations that do not work and these are tracked by Wolfram, currently as an open issue [247087].

Here is a slight modification of the original example which does not work:

[image]