# More frugal display of usage messages in auto-completion popup – possible?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete, usage-messages

**Update:** I think the more general question I should have asked is: How should I write usage messages to work well with auto-completion? Is there documentation on how to prepare a package for convenient auto-completion?

---

If I make a small function with a usage message, Mathematica will automatically extract the argument pattern from the usage  message and offer it for auto-completion:

```
f[] := 1
f::usage = "f[] returns the value.";
```

[image]

Notice that the complete usage message is echoed under the completion patters, `"f[] returns the value.", including "f[]".

This is not the case for builtins. The argument pattern is not repeated in the description.  Can I achieve this for user-defined functions?

[image]

Comment: Even using the usage messages of a built-in function in the string representation of boxes doesn't result in the desired behavior. To me it looks like the FrontEnd doesn't process user defined usage messages properly.

Comment: @Karsten7. Or maybe the reason is that it doesn't process built-in usage messages at all. Instead it gets the autocompletion information for builtins from elsewhere.

Comment: By the way, i notice that if i modify the usage message for `f`, the autocompletion doesn't take it into account, even if I quit the kernel and enter the same new usage message again ! You have to quit mma and start a new session !

Comment: Autocompletion seems to work, the only issue I see is, that the "`f[]`" part isn't removed from the second line. http://i.stack.imgur.com/arY1E.gif

Comment: @SquareOne Since I *think* 9.0.1, there's a separate auxiliary kernel the front end uses for this task.  That may be the reason why quitting the kernel doesn't fix it. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21870/12

Comment: I think some of the informations for built-in functions are stored in `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", 
  "TextResources", "English"}]`. Especially FunctionInformation2.m seems to contain the informations for the auto-completion floating box.