# Where can I find documentation on use of special characters in templates?

Tags: string-manipulation

I am new to Templates.  I have seen the usage

```
"\!\(\*StyleBox ...)"
```

as here: [disabling templates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60920/disable-templates-for-user-defined-functions-with-usages/61569#61569)  What does the string "!(*" accomplish and can I find some documentation of this notation?

Comment: These are low level formatting commands that, frankly, I seek to avoid.

Comment: Take a look at `tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes`

Comment: What do you need them for?

Comment: You would normally use `Style` in the front end rather than `StyleBox` which requires the use of other associated functions (`DisplayForm` and so on) to render correctly as output

Comment: @bbgodfrey Me too

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I agree, this was found in piece of code I inherited

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the reference,  I hope I can avoid this level of detail for now.