# Can I put Association brackets <| … |> in an autocompletion template?

Tags: associations, built-in-symbols, autocomplete

I have a function `f` which takes as one of its arguments an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) object, and I would like to produce a nice usage message for it, including a proper autocomplete template.

As an example, consider the function

```
f[association_] := {Keys[association], Values[association]}
```

which turns e.g.

```
f[<|a -> b, c -> d|>]
```

into `{{a, c}, {b, d}}`, and so on. The natural autocomplete template to use is then

```
f::usage = "f[\[LeftAssociation]a\[Rule]b,c\[Rule]d,…\[RightAssociation]] 
                returns {{a,c,…},{b,d,…}}.";
```

and it formats nicely when I ask for `?f`. However, if I try to use the template for autocomplete using Ctrl+Shift+K, I get the following:

[image]

Note, in particular, that it's somehow turned the Association symbols `<|` and `|>` into patterns to be filled in, which is obviously not the desired behaviour. This is a bit strange, particularly since `<|` is described by its documentation as a

> Matchfix operator with built-in evaluation rules.

much like `{` or `⌈`, so it cannot mean a template for some other variable. Moreover, this is independent of whether the separated form `<|` (i.e. `<` then `|`) or the single-symbol `\[LeftAssociation]` is used in the usage message string.

Is there some way to make the produced template include correctly-formatted `<|`s and `|>`s?

Comment: But then is it really going to be better for your users to get an explicit `<| a -> b... |>` with autocompletion instead of a single `assoc` pattern?  Sometimes it might be but in many cases they might want to pass a variable instead of an explicitly written out association.  That said, I'd also like this feature and +1 ...

Comment: (To be honest I won't ever be passing an explicit `<| a -> b... |>` either, but I want the template to be dead clear on what the function expects.)

Comment: Reported as a bug to WRI. Will update if I hear back from them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible.  The reason is that built-in symbols are plagued by the same problem.

[image]

I would actually consider this a bug.  It's confusing and hinders usability.  Plus, other operators, such as `->`, are not turned into patterns.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good find. I'll report it to WRI when I have time.

Comment: Note also that here `→` *is* turned into a pattern, though in general this is not the case, particularly with options.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Also, would you kindly send this link along with your report to WRI, too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/what-is-the-status-of-usage-and-templates-in-mathematica-v10-1?lq=1  ?  It's a problem that's been around for years that needs to be fixed.